# How to get attributes values using tiny radius library from radius database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, freeradius, tinyradius

I am currently working on the radius server. I am trying to get accounting data using tiny radius library in Java, but in response the attributes list is empty? What might be the reason for this or How can I get attributes and their values?

Here I am trying on Linux machine, MySQL with freeradius installed and I am trying to retrieve values from radius database.

This is how I tried and am trying to print attributes from an accounting response.

```
public void sendAuthentication() {
 RadiusClient rc = new RadiusClient("localhost", "testing123");
 AccessRequest ar = new AccessRequest("user", "123123");
 ar.setAuthProtocol(AccessRequest.AUTH_CHAP); 
 RadiusPacket response;
 try {
     response = rc.authenticate(ar);
     AccountingRequest accountingRequest = new AccountingRequest("user", ACCT_STATUS_TYPE_ACCOUNTING_ON);
     response = rc.account(accountingRequest);
     System.out.println(response.getAttributes());

 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

}